# How do I read this SD card read benchmark?

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

I run Ubuntu's "Disks" tool read benchmark against a cheap 128GB Kingston microSD (SDXC / UHS-I / ⑩ / U1) card connected via a no-name SD card reader through USB-C port to my laptop several times and got charts like this:

[image: Benchmark results]

Speed drops at 50% and access time rises. Why does it happen? Does it mean that the card is broken or about to break?

Comment: Yeah, I'd assume that the device is made from 2 64GB blocks and there is something wrong with the second one. It might be that it's using 8-bit transfer mode for the "good" block (or 4-bit w. DDR) and some broken wire might be forcing the bad block down to 1-bit mode. If I saw that graph I'd be copying off anything I cared about and replacing the card. Not 100% certain about the why, hence only a comment.

Comment: That's... weird. There are indeed probably 2 64GB modules, but not necessarily a defect one. Maybe the second one is just different, much cheaper and with much poorer performances. Just guessing... It is a new card, or a used one? I would try returning it to the vendor anyway.

Comment: @PierU using differently specced modules is still something I'd class as a defect, especially if one of those modules cannot live up to the 10MB/s the U1 designation sets as a guaranteed minimum for *write* speed. If it cannot even manage 2MB/s for reading I hate to think how bad writes would be.

Comment: Yes, it's a completely new card. And, yes, it fails U1 specs (the one that I found promise bigger values anyway).

Comment: The banchmark makes random access, am I right? I think that U1 specs are expressed in terms of sequential access. You should try benchmarking the sequential reads using `dd`

Comment: My guess would be that you got unlucky and have a module where one of the devices is not soldered down properly and one of the enhanced speed mode pins is not connecting properly. The module is working in a low speed mode. I'd send it back as defective and try a new one, if the replacement works well then fine, but if not I'd suspect either a fake or grey market device.

Comment: @PierU it looks to be a full surface test, reading 5 MB blocks spread across the disk, unlikely to be a random scan given the full surface nature of the display. It's a full disk test tool, not a random test tool like CrystalDiskMark. Looking at the settings for the tool just make it clearer it is not a random test: https://linuxhint.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/4-25.png Image from [LinuxHint](https://linuxhint.com/benchmark_hard_disks_linux/)

Comment: Then even 14MB/s in the first half is extremely bad if they are sequential reads

Comment: Thank you, folks, for your ideas and comments. I did a linear test with `dd`, the results were poor too. But I got the point: the drive is definitely not ok and should be replaced.

Comment: I've bought another card, SanDisk, 128GB SDXC / UHS-I / ⑩ / U1 / A1 from another vendor and it showed the same performance chart  I've tested all the cards I had at home and only more expensive Samsungs (same volume) show a stable chart.

Answer (score 1):

This *could* explain it, I am not saying it is *the* answer but it is based on a generic NAND mechanism:

I suppose it is possible the card was about halfway filled up with data which means the LBA addresses in this range are mapped in the FTL, a table that 'maps' LBA addresses to physical NAND addresses.

This means the other half of the LBA addresses isn't yet mapped to any physical NAND memory address. In general controller will then simply return zero filled sectors without even ever reading the NAND, and consequentially this is 'lighting' fast.

So experiment to test the theory would be be to fill up the card entirely and repeat the benchmark.

Variations may be possible too, but could still be explained by this 'effect'. As an example this SD Card was 'trimmed' (SD_ERASE):

[image]

What we see is entropy map before and after 'TRIM' on SD Card. We see zeros towards the start of the drive (black is lowest entropy), a repeating pattern towards the end. It may suggest TRIM didn't get a chance to finish and could result in the situation where first half of the drive reads fast (as NAND isn't accessed because unmapped) and second half slower.

Same effect can be observed with a SSD containing data versus a 'trimmed' SSD. TRIM 'unmaps' LBA addresses and when such addresses are read the controller returns zeros without reading the NAND (assuming Deterministic Read Zero after TRIM (RZAT) which seems most common).

*Again, this answer may not address the specific issue raised in OP, but could more generically explain dramatic speed differences between different areas on a NAND based storage device.*

Comment: It was actually a very fresh card just from the store.

Comment: What is observed by the OP is actually the opposite: fast I/Os on the first half, slow I/Os in the second half.

Comment: @PierU, Yes, you are right. I didn't look good enough. The experiment can still be done though to rule out mapped vs unmapped space.